# Send transaction with Brownie without confirmation wait

Tags: web3.py, cpp-ethereum, brownie

Is there is a way in Brownie to send a transaction without waiting for confirmation, like an async way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you just need to pass 'required_confs':0 dict with request like that:

```
token = interface.ERC20(tokenContract)
token.transfer(toAddress, amount, {'from': account, 'required_confs':0})
```